# How to split a set of strings into substrings in Python, making shorter substrings more likely?

Tags: python, string, random, gradient

I have a set of strings which are some millions of characters each. I want to split them into substrings of random length, and this I can do with no particular issue.

However, my question is: how can I apply some sort of weight to the substring length choice? My code runs in `python3`, so I would like to find a pythonic solution. In detail, my aim is to:

- split the strings into substrings that range in length between 1*e04 and 8*e06 characters.
- make it so, that the script chooses more often a short length (1*e04) over a long length (8*e06) for the newly generated substrings, like a descending length likelihood gradient.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this. I would do it as follows:

1. Take a random number `rand` in the interval `[0,1]`:

   ```
   import random
   rand = random.random()
   ```
2. Use an operation on that number to make smaller numbers more likely, but stay in the range of `[0,1]`. What operation you use depends on how you want your likelihood distribution to look like. A simple choice would be the square.

   ```
   rand = rand**2
   ```
3. Scale the number space `[0,1]` up to `[1e04, 8e06]` and round to the next integer:

   ```
   subStringLen = round(rand*(8e06-1e04)+1e04)
   ```
4. Get the substring of length `subStringLen` from your string and check how many characters are left.

   - If there are more than `8e06` characters left go to step 1.
   - If there are between `1e04` and `8e06`, use them as your last substring.
   - If there are less than `1e04` you need to decide if you want to throw the rest away or allow substrings smaller than `1e04` in this speciel case.

I'm sure there is a lot of improvements possible in terms of efficiency, this is just to give you an idea of my method.

Answer (score 2):

`NumPy` supplies lots of [random](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) samping functions. Have a look through the various [distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html#distributions) available.

If you're looking for something that it weighted towards the lower end of the scale, maybe the [exponential distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html#numpy.random.exponential) would work?

With `matplotlib` you can plot the histogram of the values, so you can get a better idea if the distribution fits what you want.

So something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# desired range of values
mn = 1e04
mx = 8e06

# random values following exp distribution
values = np.random.exponential(scale=1, size=2000)

# scale the values to the desired range
values = ((mx-mn)*values/np.max(values)) + mn

# plot the distribution of values
plt.hist(values)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```